# Merge changes between two revisions of another branche

Tags: git

It is my first experience with git and here is my problem. There is "master" branch and "temporary" branch which was branched from master branch sinse version 1. I am working in "temporary" branch and have my local changes. Now I want to merge some of "master" branch changes which were made since "secondary" branching creation.

I use TortoiseGit. So I click on my working directory, choose merge and select "master" branch. But I don't see any options to point which revisions I want to merge. If I press Ok, it says my working folder is up-to-date and doesn't merge anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of git, you should execute `git rebase master` while on the `temporary` branch. This will "add" the new `master` branch commits just before your new `temporary` branch commits (perhaps modifying them accordingly.) Look for a related operation in TortoiseGit, it is a must-have.